# Wait for a minute before call next api in c#

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-functions, delayed-execution

I want to apply delay/wait between each api call. I'm using a queue trigger. The first function will create API's and store api in a queue and next function will call the api and get the response. I want my function to be wait for a minute after the first api call and call the next api and so on.
I have applied

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

But this will wait for a min to call the first api, once the delay is complete it calls all the api in the queue without any delay.

[01/12/2018 **10:11**:05]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=10
[01/12/2018 **10:11**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=11
[01/12/2018 **10:11**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=12
[01/12/2018 **10:11**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=13

I'm expecting

[01/12/2018 **10:11**:05]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=10
[01/12/2018 **10:12**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=11
[01/12/2018 **10:13**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=12
[01/12/2018 **10:14**:06]  Delayed a min apicall https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=13

Sample code:
The code which create api call put in the queue.

```
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 40 15 * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, [Queue("topicque")] ICollector<string> outputQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(" https://weblink.com/api/v2/parent");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] =""
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                str4 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
            }
            foreach (Cat.cat cat in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cat.cat>>(str4))
            {
            long id=cat.id
            ICollector<string> collector = outputQueueItem;
            string str5 = " https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID="+id
            collector.Add(str5);
            }
            }
```

The code which trigger from queue and call the api

```
public static void Run([QueueTrigger("topicque")] string myQueueItem, [Queue("topicque")] ICollector<string> outputQueueItem2, TraceWriter log)
    {

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myQueueItem);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
         try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {

                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                str3 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                streamReader.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
                }
                }
                }
```

Is there any way we could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: @mjwills The " https://weblink.com/api/v2/parent" will result multiple values like 10,11,12,13.  And the foreach loop added to create the api with all these values like "https://weblink.com/api/v2/topics?patentID=10 and 11 and 12 and 13"

Comment: Put the delay inside the `foreach`.

Comment: @mjwills It works. Thank much for your help :)

Comment: You can also make the Run function async and call await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) instead of Thread.Sleep to avoid blocking the thread.

Comment: You pay for the running function instance no matter it is sleeping or working. Try Durable Functions on top of Azure Functions. You can wait without paying there.